# python error using PaCal statistical package

Tags: python, python-2.7, mathematical-packages

I recently started exploring Python and have encountred a problem with a package named [PaCal](http://pacal.sourceforge.net/)

Everything looks to be working fine except that I keep having this error anytime I want to print out some data (like in `print A.mean()` )
the error line is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rmobenta\Desktop\tt.py", line 12, in <module>
    print A.interval(0.95)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pacal\distr.py", line 229, in interval
    return self.quantile(p_lim), self.quantile(1.0 - p_lim)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pacal\distr.py", line 215, in quantile
    return self.get_piecewise_cdf().inverse(y)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pacal\segments.py", line 1721, in inverse
    x = findinv(segi.f,  a = segi.a, b = segi.b, c = y, rtol = params.segments.cumint.reltol, maxiter = params.segments.cumint.maxiter) # TODO PInd, MInf
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pacal\utils.py", line 384, in findinv
    return brentq(lambda x : fun(x) - c, a, b, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\zeros.py", line 414, in brentq
    raise ValueError("rtol too small (%g < %g)" % (rtol, _rtol))
ValueError: rtol too small (1e-16 < 4.44089e-16)
```

I am using a two-line script that I got for a demo (given by the author of this package) and have no idea how to tackle this issue.

Here is the script:

```
from pacal import *
Y = UniformDistr(1, 2)
X = UniformDistr(3, 4)
A = atan(Y / X)
A.plot()

print A.mean()
print A.interval(0.95)
```

Comment: please show the entire script

Comment: This happens *only* during output? Not when you assign, like `x = A.interval(0.95)`?

Comment: Actually the error is coming fron the line  A.interval(0.95). Doesn't matter if it is an output or an assignment as both produce the same error message

Comment: Do you know what version or revision of the code you are using? I've been looking through a couple versions of the source code and don't see anything about an `interval` function in the distr.py file.

Comment: I am using PaCal 1.5
Here what I found on my distr.py file 


        def interval(self, p = 0.95):    
        """Returns symmetrical interval that supports 
        p-percent of probability mass.
        
        Keyword arguments:
        p : significance level"""
        p_lim = (1.0 - p) / 2.0   
        return self.quantile(p_lim), self.quantile(1.0 - p_lim)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from PaCal that defines in `l.141` of **params.py**: `segments.vumint.reltol = 1e-16`.

This is the value passed as `rtol` in **segments.py** to the SciPy function `brentq()`.

Finally it is compared to `numpy.finfo(float).eps * 2` (`l.413` and `l.10` of **scipy/optimize/zeros.py**) and is unfortunately lesser.

So it could be a problem of PaCal implementation, not related to your code.

Note that the value you provided to `interval()` corresponds to the default value (`l.222` of **distr.py**).

I think you should contact the PaCal developers to get more informations and probably open an issue.

Comment: thanks for this answer. Is there anything we could change to adjust this? I also notice that no matter what value I give to interval() I keep getting this error

Comment: @user140061 as I said it seems to be independent from your code. The only way I see is to fix the relative tolerance of *pacal* in *params.py* (or *segments.py*), or bypass the test of the *scipy* *zero.py*. But I don't know if that can have an impact on the expected result/behaviour. That's why I advice you to contact the devs. Perhaps open an issue.